# Magento2 inline translation not working

Tags: magento2, bug, inline-translations

I am using magento 2.1.3. I am trying to enable inline translation for front end. but any how it is not working. Any js error is also not coming.

Can you please tell me why inline translation is not working in magento 2 ?

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: to be confirm you have already enabled inline translation for backend right ?

Comment: Yes I have done that also no log or js error still it is not coming on frontend.